# AsyncTask makes my app slower

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using `loadRecycleViewData()` function to call `API` for small data to display initially. And `AsyncTask` to call whole month data in a background process. Now Application becomes slower and needs to wait for 2-3 second until AsyncTask loads whole month data. Provide solution what kind changes are required in this code.

**Note: `loadRecycleViewData()` function is doing same thing like `AsyncTask` do. Because I need to show something initially when the application opens the first time.**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
    //CHECK NETWORK CONNECTION
    connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    network = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(network != null && network.isConnected()){
    loadRecycleViewData(getFirstDayDatesCurrentMonth(), getLastDayDatesCurrentMonth());
    new ApiRequest().execute(); //HERE ASYNCTASK CALLED TO FETCH DATA FROM API

}}

//loadRecycleViewData() function
private void loadRecycleViewData(final String start, final String end) {
    String URL_DATA = "https://api.example.com/calendar&f=json";
    //Log.e("URL_DATA",""+URL_DATA);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    final RealmHelperCalendar helper = new RealmHelperCalendar(realm);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            //SET DATA
                            Calendar calendar = new Calendar();

                            JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String CalendarId = o.getString("CalendarId");
                            String Date = o.getString("Date");

                            String[] separated = Date.split("T");
                            String inputDateFormat = separated[0] + " " + separated[1];
                            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
                            Date result =  df.parse(inputDateFormat);
                            Long milisecond = getMiliSecondFromDate(inputDateFormat);

                            calendar.setId(CalendarId);
                            calendar.setDate(result);

                            helper.save(calendar)); //SAVE IN REALM DB
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

//AsyncTask Background Function
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    String URL_DATA = "https://api.example.com/calendarf=json";
    final RealmHelperCalendar helper = new RealmHelperCalendar(realm);
    try {

        URL url = new URL(URL_DATA);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.connect();

        BufferedReader bufR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String response = bufR.readLine();


        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

            Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
            JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String CalendarId = o.getString("CalendarId");
            String Date = o.getString("Date");

            String[] separated = Date.split("T");
            String inputDateFormat = separated[0] + " " + separated[1];
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
            java.util.Date result =  df.parse(inputDateFormat);
            Long milisecond = getMiliSecondFromDate(inputDateFormat);

            calendar.setId(CalendarId);
            calendar.setDate(result);

            helper.save(calendar)); //SAVE IN REALM DB
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Update your post with async code

Comment: Or maybe the slow method is `loadRecycleViewData()`

Comment: `... to call API for small data ...` why can't you simply use a very quick database table?

Comment: I have edited the code in question, please take a look, when I comment new ApiRequest().execute(); it works fine but when I call AsyncTask it takes load and make app slower.

Comment: @Bernoulli Gate, Actually when the user opens the app first time I need to show today's data which comes from the API and store it into the realm database, and then its loading in recycleview. And in background I want to call for whole month data, which user gonna use in while for further views.

Comment: When the user has internet in mobile it will load newer data that's why I need to store data into the database initially after that showing in recycleview. If no internet user is able to see that data which already preloaded.

Comment: An offline database can perform very fast, if correctly indexed. An online database is subject to the connectivity status.

Comment: Data is loading from local database only, but the condition is this "If internet connection is there it will load new data from the API and update into the database"

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will try your edited code and will come back.